# Import data including numbers into a SQL DB from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to import data and one of the columns(username) is zeros with numbers (002317) into a SQL DB from Excel sheet. The column(username) is special number in Excel however when I import the file, this column(username) gets mapped to a VARCHAR2 type , the result in the SQL table is (2317.00) not (002317), how I can import it like (002317)?

Comment: First save the file as `CSV`, do not open it with excel (When you will open it in excel, it will convert `002317` to `2317` as it is a number).So, direct import that CSV.

Comment: it works with me now but I loss some data in Arabic with this format

Comment: I do not work with other language except `English`. Not sure.

Comment: VARCHAR2? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

Make another column in your excel with this formula:

```
RIGHT("00000" & A1, 6)
```

Where A1 is the cell that contains `2317` as a number. This will make a string out of the number. Use that in your import instead

Or

Do your import as normal, then run this query:

```
UPDATE table SET column = LPAD(columnX + 0, 6, '0')
```

It will convert your column to a number (`"2317.00" -> 2317`) then convert it back to text and pad it out to 6 chars wide

Comment: thank you, RIGHT("00000" & A1, 6) work with me fine